# Unique sequential numbers, when using a queue (1 worker)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to generate unique,sequential invoice numbers. The invoices are generated using a queue, with 1 worker, but out of 160 invoices 28 still end up with duplicate numbers. 
Below is the code used to generate a unique invoice number.

```
public static function getNewInvoiceNumber(String $prefix)
{
    $lastNumber = App\Invoice::where('invoiceNumber', 'LIKE', $prefix . now()->year . '-%')->orderByDesc('invoiceID')->first()->invoiceNumber ?? '0';
    $newNumber = (int)substr($lastNumber, strlen($prefix . now()->year . '-')) + 1;

    while (App\Invoice::where('invoiceNumber', $prefix . now()->year . '-' . $newNumber)->exists()) {
        $newNumber++;
    }

    return $newNumber;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to give a UNIQUE constrain to the invoiceNumber field? You only have to catch the expection and, eventually, retry.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but I'd rather not rely on catching exceptions and just trying again.

Comment: I am not sure if it solves the issue but I am using 
    ->value(DB::raw("MAX(invoiceNumber COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)")) instead of ->orderByDesc('invoiceID')->first()->invoiceNumber and works for me

Comment: I think the problem is ordering by invoiceID, not invoiceNumber

Comment: If it's not a Visual Harmonization problem, then you could add the result of `time()` in PHP to it which is a unique timestamps during 1 second. And if you couple that with some Product - Vendor CODE, that should be unique even if 2 invoices are created the same second